# Best Practices for Managing Concurrent Client Connections in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Hello Cassandra Community,

We've been experiencing occasional spikes in the number of client connections to our Cassandra cluster, particularly during high-volume API request periods. We're using persistent connections, and we've noticed that the number of connections can increase significantly during these spikes.

We're considering using the following Cassandra parameters to manage concurrent client connections:

**native_transport_max_concurrent_connections**: This parameter sets the maximum number of concurrent client connections allowed by the native transport protocol. Currently, it's set to -1, indicating no limit.

**native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip**: This parameter sets the maximum number of concurrent client connections allowed per source IP address. Like the previous parameter, it's also set to -1.

We're thinking of using these parameters to limit the maximum number of connections from a single IP address, especially to prevent overwhelming the database during spikes in API requests that should be handled by our SOA team exclusively.

Are these parameters suitable for production use, and would implementing restrictions on concurrent connections per IP be considered a good practice in managing Cassandra clusters?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Naman Kaushik